# Laravel: create a fake belongsToMany withPivot relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have a `belongsToMany()` relationship between a `User` and a `Group`. The user has a `level` within any group he belongs to.

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'user_group', 'user_id', 'group_id')
                ->withPivot('level');
}
```

This works great.

However if the `User` is an admin, I would like the groups function to return ALL `Group`s with `level = 3`, regardless of whether that relationship exists in the pivot table or not.

I can successfully create a `Collection` which mirrors the data structure as follows:

```
    \App\Group::all()->transform(function ($item, $key) use ($uid) {
        $item->pivot = collect(['user_id'=>$uid,'group_id'=>$item->id,'level'=>3]);
        return $item;
    });
```

However, I cannot substitute the two outputs as one returns a `belongsTo` relationship instance and the other returns a `Collection`. This means I can call `->get()` on the former but not the latter.

I thought about using the `DB::` facade and creating a `Builder` for the latter, but I cannot add the Pivot values manually.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

-- UPDATE --

I am currently cheating by adding the `->get()` inside the `groups()` method, but this is messy and I would still like to know if there is a better way to solve this problem.

```
public function groups()
{
    if ($this->isAdmin()) {

        return \App\Group::all()->transform(function ($item, $key) use ($uid) {
            $item->pivot = collect(['user_id'=>$uid,'group_id'=>$item->id,'level'=>3]);
            return $item;
        });

    } else { 

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'user_group', 'user_id', 'group_id')
                ->withPivot('level')->get();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So this solution should work(not tested), but it is not the "cleanest" it would be better to access all groups through some other mechanism but because I don't know your admin implemention it is hard to guess.

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'user_group', 'user_id', 'group_id')
        ->withPivot('level');
}

public function scopeSpecialGroups($query)
{
    return $query->when($this->role === 'admin',function($query){
            return Group::where('level', '>', 3');
        })->when($this->role != 'admin',function($query){
            return $query->with('groups');
        });
}
```

Then you should be able to call `User::specialGroups()->get();`

Comment: Thanks - I'm not clear what `$query` would be passed to `scopeGroups`, though? Also the 'level' is a pivot value, not an attribute on `Group`. However, your `allGroups()` function could be replaced with `Group::where('id','>',0)` for example.

Comment: So it is a query scope, which means the $query var would be automatically inserted by Laravel when using the scope. So when you call User::groups()->get(); it should be using the scope.

Renamed it so it would make more sense
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: Thanks again, I am now running into a similar problem as before, in that I am getting an exception in Builder line 555 that `Builder::addEagerConstraints()` doesn't exist. I.e. the `allGroups` function is returning a `Builder`, when it needs to return a `Relation` (as only `Relation::addEagerConstrains()` exists).

Comment: Changed some code getting error because "with" wants a relation, the updated answer should work I tested it and i worked fine. Remember that the $this->role is something that I have that will need to be changed to how you identify your admin user

Comment: Keep in mind that with this solution the second query will return Users with relation groups, while the first will only return Group collections

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the original issue of having the `level` as a pivot on the `Group` instance. Per my previous comment, the `level` is per user per group (not an attribute on `Group`). The structure of your 'when role is admin' return does not match the structure of the `belongsToMany()->withPivot()`.